# Is it possible to place the .irbrc file in the project folder?

Tags: ruby, irb

I would like to place the .irbrc file in my project folder to configure the irb console just for that specific project. I am aware that i can configure .irbrc placing it in the home folder but i would like to avoid that, i just want to require all the files of my project when i get into the console, but i am not looking for a permanent behaviour
     I am trying to place .irbrc file in the project root but it does not seem to be requiring anything if i place it there.
       Is it possible to do it??.
      Any suggestion would be much appreciated. 
        Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your project have a `./bin/console` file? Probably that's what you're looking for.

Here is some information about it: [Your Ruby App Should Have a `bin/console`](https://mutelight.org/bin-console).

However, you can pass another file to be loaded in `irb`:

```
IRBRC="~/Documents/.irbrc" irb
```

You can look at how `irb` loads it in [init.rb](https://github.com/ruby/irb/blob/master/lib/irb/init.rb#L270), if you're interested.

Comment: Thank you so much Matheus, I barely understand a word of what you said I ve started coding just 3 months ago and this kind of configurations drive me crazy.  I reckon that with your answer I will be able to advance in the rigth direction!

Comment: I had time to research a bit about your suggestion, and definitely i was able to configure my project as i wanted!!!. Thank you so much!!, the bin/console trick is really cool!!.

Comment: I'm really happy you were able to do what you wanted. Yes, `bin/console` is very cool and it is great when you work in a project that the programmers took time to carefully configure a nice `bin/console`.